# Selecting sibling nodes using position()

Tags: dom, xpath

I've got a trouble selecting divs following specific title in code:

```
<div>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
```

I was trying to get the nodes using preceding-sibling somehow like this:

```
//div/div[preceding-sibling::h2[1][position()=1]]
```

I need all divs which have the NEAREST preceding h2 sibling on position 1, but I'm still getting all 5 items.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Example output with position 1 (section 1):

```
<div>Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
```

Example output with position 2 (section 2):

```
<div>Item 3</div>
<div>Item 4</div>
<div>Item 5</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a tricky thing to do, but one approach you can use is `count()`:

```
//div/div[count(preceding-sibling::h2) = 1]
```

The reason your attempt with `position()` didn't work is that `position()` is evaluated relative to the current selection. With `preceding-sibling::h2[1][position()=1]`, you are selecting the nearest `h2` and then selecting the first node *in that set*.